# PhMagick Crop Function Echoes Convert with Debug Disabled

Tags: php, imagemagick, phmagick

Right now I'm in the process of switching my site over from one host to another, and phMagick is acting up on the new server. I have a page that allows users to upload an image via ajax, and the server uses phMagick to crop the image, then create a few resized versions and upload them to S3. Right now, this works perfectly except that the `convert` command used to crop the image is echoed, and the javascript doesn't know how to handle this because it breaks the format of the JSON response.

Here is the relevant part of the server side script:

```
require_once(BASE_PATH . "/library/phmagick/phmagick.php");     
$phmagick = new phMagick( "{$base}{$uncropped}", "{$base}{$cropped}" );
$phmagick->debug = false;
$phmagick->setImageQuality(100);
$phmagick->crop( $dimensions['width'], $dimensions['height'], $dimensions['y'], $dimensions['x'], 'NorthWest' );


//Generate the large
$phmagick->setSource("{$base}{$cropped}");
$phmagick->setDestination("{$base}{$large}");
$phmagick->resize(640, 640);

//Generate the small
$phmagick->setDestination("{$base}{$small}");
$phmagick->resize(220, 220);

//Generate the thumbnail
$phmagick->setDestination("{$base}{$thumbnail}");
$phmagick->resize(100, 100);
```

As you can see, I have debug set to false, and I'm not echoing anything in there. Here's the output that is messing with my javascript:

```
convert $snip_path/10001_uncropped.jpg -gravity NorthWest -crop 399x399+71+0 $snip_path/10001_cropped.jpg{$json_response}
```

Strangely, you can see that I crop the image, then resize it 3 times, but only the crop is output like this. Also, it only outputs the command itself, and nothing like "An error occurred." I don't see anything in the `phMagick_crop` class that looks like it might be responsible for the message.

What else might this be? I don't see anything in my code, and I don't see anything in the phMagick code. I don't know where else to look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I'm an idiot. I'm using phMagick on two different sites, so I was inspecting the source of the one that was more convenient. Turns out the two copies weren't identical. At some point someone added an echo $cmd into the crop class to debug it, and forgot to take it out.